# Multiple different classpaths during maven test execution

Tags: java, maven, classpath, integration-testing, maven-failsafe-plugin

For a java project I want to spin up a server application during integration test (`maven-failsafe-plugin`, can be switched).

## Problem

- The server application should be fetched via maven
- My project and the server depend on a shared library

  - The version of my copy of the shared lib may be different then the one of the server application

(During test there is even a third application involved, but the same requirements apply)

## Current solution

- Create a classloader manually, built classpath manually, start server application in custom classpath

  - manual dependency resolution sucks. Has to be redone on dependency changes.
- Put everything onto the classpath, remove stuff that breaks.

  - Also manual...

## Wish

- Specify a "dependency profile" in `pom.xml` for each component
- During test call something like: `Maven.getClassLoaderForProfile("server")`, receiving a classloader with all dependencies (including transitive ones)
- Load application in this classloader